# How can I show a .txt file contents in a meteor (blaze) app?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to read the contents of a .txt file and show them in a Meteor app.
The problem is that I need the file loaded without the need of an input from the user and also that file is being updated almost every 3 seconds from another program. I can't access to the file if it isn't inside the server folder using

```
file///C:/path/to/file/file.txt
```

but if I use a script to copy that file to the server's folder every X seconds, then Meteor starts to rebuild the whole app interrupting any user filling forms.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I tried inserting the file in "public" but client keeps refreshing after file.txt is edited. I ended up using Collections inserted from the server and loaded from the client, but now I will check how to detect file changes that update the Collection automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in the `/public` directory and then you can serve it from a relative path starting at that point. For example:

```
/public/dynamicFiles/file.txt
```

Can be served from your app as

```
/dynamicFiles/file.txt
```

Files under `/public` do not cause app rebuilds and are directly accessible (no security).

If you need your file to be secured or you don't want to be copying it all the time then you'll want to use [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) on the server to access it directly from its original directory (which can be an absolute path).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. I know I can serve files like this:
"<img src="/images/kitten.png">" but since I'm using iron-router, I got a message that the route is not defined, that's why I'm having trouble.

Comment: You can't use i-r to just serve a file out of public afaik.